# Jquery DatePicker Change with dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown and JQuery UI Date Picker. Consider Dropdown has two values Sunday and Monday. If I choose Sunday in the dropdown, I want to disable all the Sundays in the calendar. If I choose Monday in the dropdown, I want to enable Sunday and disable Monday
in the datepicker. When the page loads for the first time, it works fine. But when I change the dropdown value, date picker value is not changing, it still disables the old values.

Comment: I suggest providing your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/35/)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    inline: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var val = parseInt($('#temp').val());
        var day = date.getDay();
        console.log(day, val)
        return [val == day ? false : true]
    },
    altField: '#alternate',
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="temp">
  <option value=1>Monday</option>
  <option value=0>Sunday</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```